# Mocking a method on dynamically allocated instance?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Background: I'm working on an MVC framework for some practice, and want to make sure everything is 100% unit tested.

The setup currently is to have an instance of the application class (`Ex_App`). The main script asks a Dispatcher/Router for a controller name. This controller name is the name of a class implementing `Ex_Controller`. The result is returned as an instance of `Ex_Dispatch_Result`. This result is passed to the `Ex_App` instance using an `invokeController($dispatchResult)` function.

And this is where magic happens. The listing below is an excerpt:

```
$controllerName = $dispatchResult->getControllerName();
... checks for validaty of class name ...
$controller = new $controllerName();
$controller->prepare($this);
```

I'm using PHPUnit to do my unit testing, and am able to mock the dispatch result, correctly check that validating the class name of the controller works. The problem is how to check if prepare is called.

I'd like to do something similar to:

```
$mockController = $this->getMockBuilder('Ex_Controller')
  ->setMockClassName('Invoke_Correct_Controller')
  ->getMock();
$mockController->expects($this->once())->method('prepare');
```

However since a new instance of `Invoke_Correct_Controller` is created upon calling `invokeController`, it will not be this mock and thus the `expects()` call is completely irrelevant.

I could make the `Ex_Dispatch_Result` class responsible for returning a controller and testing that, but before returning an instance I will need to verify the correctness of the class name and in my opinion that responsibility should be with the `Ex_App` class and not the "dumb shell" `Ex_Dispatch_Result` class.

Is there something I am missing in the PHPUnit framework that I could use to test the code here, or some useful pattern that could work in my instance? I feel passing around controller names scales way better than passing around instances of controllers from the start, requiring the initialization of every possible controller. So, I kinda want to stick to passing around names and using the `Ex_App` as a factory for the controller instance.

Maybe I'm just over-thinking part of this problem, but that happens sometimes. It's why a fresh look by a third party often works :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things you could do:

- Extract controller creation logic to separate class e.g. ControllerFactory, and then mock controller factory instance, so that it returns your $mockController.
- Extract controller creation logic to separate method and use partial mocking.
- Return $mockController from $dispatchResult->getControllerName(), which probably requires mocking of $dispatchResult or even something else.

If you want more detailed answer, please provide more code samples of your classes and methods.